# Render table with react after acquiring data through JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem while trying to display data with React. The data is first calculated in a normal JS function and isn't ready by the time React renders its' table...

this is the call to a JS function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        derivePairs();
        alert(config.pairs.length);
    });
</script>
```

The function determines round robin pairs (config.pairs is the global variable for them) for a simulated football league. I would like to display those pairs in a React rendered table.

This is the React code for table rendering...

```
var Table = React.createClass({

      getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: this.props.data};
      },

      render: function() {
          var headerComponents = this.generateHeaders(),
              rowComponents = this.generateRows();

          return (
              <table>
                  <thead>{headerComponents}</thead>
                  <tbody>{rowComponents}</tbody>
              </table>
          );
      },

      generateHeaders: function() {
          var cols = this.props.cols;  // [{key, label}]

          // generate our header (th) cell components
          return cols.map(function(colData) {
              return <th key={colData.key}>{colData.label}</th>;
          });
      },

      generateRows: function() {
          var cols = this.props.cols,  // [{key, label}]
              data = this.props.data;

          alert(this.props.data.length);
          var dataMap = this.props.data.map(function(item) {
            alert(item.homeTeam);
          });

          return this.state.data.map(function(item) {
              // handle the column data within each row
              alert(item);
              var cells = cols.map(function(colData) {
                  alert("test");
                  console.log(colData);
                  // colData.key might be "firstName"
                  return <td> {item[colData.key]} </td>;
              });
              return <tr key={item.id}> {cells} </tr>;
          });
      }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(<Table cols={columns} data={config.pairs}/>, document.getElementById('roundPairs'));
```

Now I understand why config.pairs is empty by the time React renders, I would need some help on how to pass those values to React when they are calculated...please help if you can.

Comment: why don't you call this instruction ReactDOM.render(<Table cols={columns} data={config.pairs}/>, document.getElementById('roundPairs')); just after your alert(config.pairs.length);

Comment: I tried doing that first thing, but got an error saying: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" where render(<Table excerpt is.

Comment: because it's jsx syntax you need to transpile it to pure javascript

Comment: In pure js it will be like this ReactDOM.render( React.createElement('Table', { 'cols': columns, 'data': config.pairs }), document.getElementById('roundPairs'));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three options.

The first one is to delay the rendering of the `Table` component until the data is ready. This could be achieved by passing the rendering code as a callback to the `derivePairs` function. Personally, I find this a really clumsy way of achieving the desired result.

The other way is to use life cycle methods of React components. In your case `componentWillMount` makes the most sense. You can run the code that gets your data here and when it's available, you can set the state accordingly and React will re-render your component with the new data. This is a nice solution to your problem but it also binds the data fetching logic to your `Table` component. This could or could not work depending on your design and future needs.

The best way to do it in my opinion is to create another component that actually wraps the `Table` component. It will manage data fetching itself and pass the relevant data to the `Table` component. This way your `Table` component will not need to know how to fetch its data and it will correctly render with the data you pull/generate.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try the third way. Didn't even think of that